# How does a Kindle (or iPad) know when I close the lid?

Tags: sleep, ipad, case, kindle

How does a Kindle (or iPad) go to sleep when I close the lid of the case? Does it just detect something like going into complete darkness, or is it related to the magnet?

Comment: For I cannot search any other answer about this in google, I come here and get my right answer, and so my upvote in both this question and accepted answer in spite of the wrong scope of this question in superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it senses the presence or absence, or possibly movement, of a magnet in the cover. Here is an article from someone who built their own cover, with magnet: http://blog.workingsi.com/2013/01/paperwhite-kindle-cover-how-to-add.html